# How to skip already existing files when downloading with curl?

Tags: curl, command-line, download

I want to `curl` to download a link, but I want it to skip files that already exist. Right now, the line of code I have will continue to overwrite it no mater what:

```
curl '$url' -o /home/$outputfile &>/dev/null &
```

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could just put your call to `curl` inside an `if` block:

```
if ! [ -f /home/$outputfile ]; then
  curl -o /home/$outputfile "url"
fi
```

Also note that in your example, you've got `$url` inside single quotes, which won't do what you want.  Compare:

```
echo '$HOME'
```

To:

```
echo "$HOME"
```

Also, `curl` has a `--silent` option that can be useful in scripts.

Comment: very helpful, thank you for pointing that out. but I am doing this via php, how can i run that if statement via php?

Comment: I don't know PHP off the top of my head, but I'm sure it has a relatively simple mechanism for seeing if a file exists.

Comment: Well with a curl config file to fetch 1000 files (to reduce DNS queries) it is a shame that we have to now have the shell check each time, as there is no way to do the exact same test in curl itself.

Answer (score 47):

You can use curl option `-C -`. This option is used to resume a broken download, but will skip the download if the file is already complete. Note that the argument to `-C` is a single dash. A disadvantage might be that curl still briefly contacts the remote server to ask for the file size.

Comment: Can't download file (file does not exist) if the server doesn't support to resume. Error: curl: (33) HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume.

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI Try https://github.com/curl/curl

Comment: Doesn't work with `-J`: `curl: --continue-at and --remote-header-name cannot be combined`

Answer (score 21):

Use wget with `--no-clobber` instead:

> `-nc`, `--no-clobber`: skip downloads that would download to existing files.

Example:

```
wget -nc -q -O "/home/$outputfile" "$url"
```

Comment: can you please guide me on how to use with wget?

Comment: Initially I was using wget, but then I changed to curl because I wanted the newly downloaded file to have the timestamp of when it was downloaded. using wget, it does not generate new timestamp but instead whatever timestamp is from the source it copied. how do i have wget generating new timestamps?

Comment: `-N` turns-off timestamping in wget.

Comment: The -nc option will not download newer files. **Use `-N` instead**, it will download and overwrite the file if there's a newer version.

Comment: "use wget" doesn't seem to be the answer to "how do I do this with curl"...

Answer (score 3):

The `curl` may support skipping the files when you use it with `-O` and `-J`, but its behaviour is inconsistent.

The `-J` (`--remote-header-name`) basically tells the `-O` (`--remote-name`) option to use the server-specified `Content-Disposition` filename instead of extracting a filename from the URL. In that way the `curl` doesn't really know what file name the server will return, so it may ignore the existing file for a safety precaution.

<sup>Source: [Re: -J "Refusing to overwrite..."](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2014-05/0042.html)</sup>

For example:

```
$ curl -LJO -H 'Accept: application/octet-stream' 'https://api.github.com/repos/x/y/releases/assets/12345
Warning: Refusing to overwrite my_file.bin: File 
Warning: exists
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16384)
```

However as mentioned already, its behaviour is unpredictable and it doesn't work for all the files.

Answer (score 3):

As of [version 7.83](https://curl.se/changes.html#7_83_0), released on 27th  April 2022, `curl` now has a `--no-clobber` option, just like `wget`, which will do almost what you want.

Comment: Your post is here forever, so what is "recent"? Please update this to say as of which version that option exists.

Comment: Nope, this just writes to `filename.1` when `filename` exists. You'd think skipping existing files would be a really basic feature, but it's unsupported.