# Downloading a list of files, incrementing filename with each iteration

Tags: unix, curl, xargs

I'm using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865866/pipe-output-of-cat-to-curl-to-download-a-list-of-files) to help me download a list of files into a directory. However, if I want to actually download them, I need to specify a filename to save as too. Here's what I have so far:

```
$ xargs -n 1  curl > newname.html -0 < ../list.txt
```

It's going through the list fine, but it appears that it's always overwriting `newname.html` with each iteration. How do I number the downloads so that I have 'newname1', 'newname2', and so on? I don't really understand terminal commands all that well so I don't even know where to begin with deciperhing this. I've basically just combined typical cURL download command and that thread I linked above about going down the list to get where I am.

Comment: You should try a copy&paste of the actual answer given (or perhaps the suggestion given in the comment on the question), instead of trying to  re-type it.  Hint:  0 != O

Comment: 0 is not equal to O. Thanks! By some miracle, I have it working now. I guess that's what I get for not figuring out how it works, but then again I still am a little lost.

Comment: Actually I think this is a good question. wget does this automatically, but as Mark points out, curl does not. However there are reasons why you might want to use curl instead of wget in certain situations - for example at the moment I need to specify proxies, so with curl I can do that via a command line argument, whereas with wget the proxy setting is system wide. See this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856351/curl-dont-download-or-overwrite-file-if-exists